# Possible to upgrade 12.04->12.10, not 13x?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

Can I upgrade to a specific version, rather than to whatever's newest? I've a driver to install which requires 12.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using 12.04, the next release *is* 12.10. it is only possible to go from one release to the next....with the exception of LTS, you can upgrade from one LTS to the next LTS(i.e.12.04 to 14.04)  To get to 13.10 for example, you would have to upgrade 3 times- 12.10, 13.04, 13.10.  See the answer below for info on upgrading to 12.10 from 12.04

Answer (score 2):

Upgrades are possible from any release to the next, or from one LTS release to the next LTS release.
That is, you can upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 ONLY, and later to 14.04 as both 12.04 & 14.04 are LTS. But, 12.04 to 13.04 isn't possible directly, you'd have to upgrade twice.

In Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), run this command when connected to a high-speed internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get do-release-upgrade
```

It'd upgrade you to 12.10 only. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by:

```
sudo apt-get do-release-upgrade
```

For exact info of what this command does, see: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html